# ASP page load time device-to-device

Tags: asp.net, windows, performance

I have been developing an internal website for some time.  The pages are aspx, and the server is using IIS. For some reason I am seeing a huge difference in page load time on Windows devices.  Mobile devices are quick, and pretty uniform.  Windows 10 devices, there is a big difference device to device.  My PC, which I've used for development, loads a page in 763ms.  Another Windows 10 PC takes from 5 seconds to 11 seconds to load the same page - even when the server is idling.

I have noticed that Windows PC's that have previously had Visual Studio on them (VS version doesn't seem to matter) seem to load within 1 second.  Windows PC's that have not have VS installed take much longer to load the same page - 5 - 15 seconds.

If I use Google Chrome's performance profiler, it appears to be the network request that varies in time.  The page render time is similar across devices.

Can anyone help me with why this might be happening?  Or maybe thoughts of what things I might try to improve the performance on the slower devices?

Many thanks!

Comment: Could be the local dns that takes that much time to answer?

Comment: Thanks Wiktor.  We are using the IP address in the URL (since it's an internal site only).  If I replace the IP address with the DNS name, it takes 0.1 seconds longer to load - both on slow devices and faster ones. ‍♂️

Comment: try pinging from the various machines and see if there is any difference in response. Try profiling a 'known' external site from the various machines and see if there are any differences.

Comment: What about static resources? The issue is specific to asp or static resources also load slower?

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Ping times on the various machines to known sites were the same across all machines. Profiling known sites produced the same times across all devices too.  Turns out I had a function that was taking different times on different machines because of the info I was passing it.  Then a client script followed, which produced even more variance from machine to machine.  Looks like this is the issue.  When I disabled these functions/scripts, the load times evened out over the various machines.  Thank you all for your support!!